# Regarding Super keyword?

Tags: java, constructor, keyword, super

What is the need for the JVM to call superclass constructor?

```
public class Test1{
    public void dis()
    {
        System.out.println("In Test1");
    }
}

public class Test2 extends Test1{
    public void dis()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside test2");
        super.dis();
    }
}
```

Since `dis()` is an instance method, is it safe to assume that super is pointing to parent class object since the constructor is automatically called?

Comment: sorry..System.out.println

Comment: By the way, you can easily test it,, Just have a main and run your program.

Comment: The superclass constructor is not involved in the code you posted.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632882/calling-super

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `super` does not point to some "parent class object". It is a name qualifier so you can refer to a method defined in the parent class *for the current object*. Thus, in the following:

```
public class Test2 extends Test1{
    public void dis()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside test2");
        super.dis();
    }
}
```

the call `super.dis()` invokes the `dis()` method defined in the parent class *for this object*. It does not invoke the `dis()` method of some other object named `super`.

Slightly different things are going on with constructors. Every constructor must always start with a call to some constructor in the parent class. You can do this explicitly using the `super` keyword:

```
public class Test2 extends Test1{
    public Test2() {
        super(); // explicitly invokes parent class default constructor
        . . .
    }
}
```

If you don't explicitly call a particular parent class constructor, the compiler automatically inserts a call to the default (no-argument) parent class constructor. The call to a parent class constructor (if present) must be the first statement in a constructor. Within a method, however, `super.` can be used as a qualifier for any name wherever it is used (provided the name is a member of the parent class).

Answer (score 1):

The `super` keyword is useful for:

- Calling the superclass' implementation of a method overriden in this class
- Accessing the superclass' constructor from a subclass constructor

Your example shows the first case in action, when calling `dis()` on an instance of `Test2` the program must print, in this order:

```
Inside test2 
In Test1
```

Answer (score 1):

> is it safe to assume that super is pointing to parent class object

`super` keyword is used to access *direct super class* members on the current object. It does not refer to any super class object.

> since constructor is automaticallt called?

The role of `super` keyword is not dependent upon the super class constructor being called. Super class constructor is always called through constructor chaining using `super()` call to either no-arg or parameterized constructor.

One difference between chaining super class constructor, and invoking super class member is that: "While chaining constructors, the `super()` call has to be the first statement in constructor, while you can invoke super class method at any point in your current method".

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with constructors. Since `Test2 extends Test1` and dis() is implemented in both classes, super.dis() in the subclass will call dis() in the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

using super constructor we can call functions and variables directly from
   super class in subclass for

---

```
public class Test1{
 int a=5;
  } 
 public class Test2 extends Test1{
  int a=15;
  int c;
   c=a+super.a;
  System.out.println("value of c is:"+
  }
   result :value of c is:20
  you can call default constructor of super class by super() .
  if there is variables then you can call it by super(parameter_list).
```