# Why exception should be handled in inheritance since constructors are not inherited?

Tags: java

As I know that constructor are not inherited.

Then what's reason to handle exception in child constructor. Is there some where behind the scene some one is creating parent object while we create object of child or what ?

```
public class Parent {
    public Parent() throws Exception{

    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public Child(){ // compile time error "Unhandled Exception Type"

    }
}
```

I am not trying to init parent class by calling `Super()` inside child constructor. I do not understand why we have to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `super()` is implicitly called. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632882/calling-super

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With reference to [JLS 8.8.7 Constructor Body](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7)

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation ... then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation super();

In other words, the following code is semantically identical to your `Child` class' definition:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    public Child(){ // compile time error "Unhandled Exception Type"
      super();  // This throws Exception.
    }
}
```

This has to happen because the initialization which is necessary to initialize the `Parent` instance must happen. Consider what would happen if the super constructor were not called:

```
class Parent {
  private final Frobnitz foo;

  Parent() throws Exception {
    foo = new Frobnitz();
  }

  void doSomething() {
    foo.doYourFrobbing();
  }
}

class Child extends Parent { ... }

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Child().doSomething();  // Would cause a NPE unless Parent() is called (implicitly or explicitly).
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Got it.

Comment: This answer would be even better if it started with a reference to [JLS 8.8.7 Constructor Body](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7): "*If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation ... then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation `super();`*"

Answer (score 3):

If you create an object of type child, the constructor of the super class is called (explicitly or implicitly). That's why you need to catch the Exception.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't call `super()` explicitly in the child class's constructor, it is called implicitly, so you must catch the exception, or declare that your child class's constructor throws Exception.