# How can we call abstract class constructor?

Tags: java, abstract-class

```
 public abstract class MyAbstractClass{
     public MyAbstractClass(){
         System.out.println("MyAbstractClass Constructor");
     }
 }
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: You can call it from the constructor in a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `super()` in the child class which extends this abstract class.
For ex:

```
public class MyAbstractClassImpl extends MyAbstractClass {

    public MyAbstractClassImpl() {
         super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         MyAbstractClassImpl obj = new MyAbstractClassImpl();
    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't it called by default? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2632918/2067492

Comment: You don't need to add `super()`, it is called implicitly when there is no explicit constructor call in the sub-class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call directly the constructor of an abstract class, i.e. you are not allowed to create instances of an abstract class. The constructor(s) should actually be `protected` and not `public`. So either you have an anonymous class overriding the abstract parts or a non-abstract sub-class of your abstract class. Then the constructor is explicitly called via `super()` as mentioned in the other posts.

Answer (score -1):

Try using super() in a child class.

```
 public abstract class MyAbstractClass{
    public MyAbstractClass(){
     System.out.println("MyAbstractClass Constructor");
    }
    }

public class Child extends MyAbstractClass{

    public Child() {
        super();
        System.out.println("Child!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Child();
    }
}
```

Comment: @matt I mean yeah it does it automatically, but how do u suppose to answer OP's question?

Comment: You need to create an implementation, super should be called automatically.